# QuickBooks - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: iis, asmx, quickbooks

I am trying to connect to https://subdomain.mysite.com/qbwebservice.asmx using the QuickBooks Web Connector. I am getting a connection issue:

**20130617.18:20:07 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() :  Error message:  One or more errors occurred. ---> An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Unable to connect to the remote server ---> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [MY IP]>**

My code works fine on my local machine. I believe this is a server related issue.

1. Can the Intuit Web Connector connect to a sub-domain?
2. When the user visits the IP, the user sees a generic II7 page. Visiting [myip]/qbwebservice.asmx throws a 404 error.

What is the best way to set-up this connection?

Comment: What is the actual URL you have it pointed to? subdomain.mysite.com is not a valid domain name. If you post the actual URL, we can probably test and get an idea of what's going on. The Web Connector should have no problem connecting to any domain name.

Answer (score 0):

We found out the web connector cannot work on a web farm. The IP the connector was using was incorrect. The connector tries to resolve a host name to an IP. The IP must be static and never change.